# Nested "if" statement in for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having some difficulty figuring this out. The question in my assignment asks that we:

> Print the elements in the `nmrls` list that have more than or equal to 7 letters and has either the letter 'o' or the letter 'g'.

and the results should be three (`eighteen`, `fourteen` and `twenty-one`) but I only get twenty-one.

What am I doing wrong?

Also unrelated question, do we always have to run the entire code every time we open Jupyter notebook (for a sophisticated language it seems very cumbersome)?

```
nmrls = inflect.engine()
x=[]
for i in range (0,22):
    x.append(nmrls.number_to_words(i))   
for nmrls in x:
    count=0
    for letter in nmrls:
        count+=1
        if count>=7 and "o"  or "g" :   
            print(nmrls)
```

Comment: First, there is no such thing as an "if loop".
Second, you haven't compared anything to those two letters.  Your posted code does not run as given, so it's hard for us to handle your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that what you need is a loop body that actually checks the word in question:

```
for word in x:
    if len(word) >= 7 and ('o' in word or 'g' in word):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections: hand-typing my code from the IDLE window.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because your `if` statement doesn't actually check if 'o' or 'g' is in the string, but whether 'o' or 'g' exists, due to the [inherent true boolean value of non-zero length strings](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) in Python.

I would recommend reimplementing this using [len():](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

```
for nmrls in x:
    if len(nmrls) >= 7 and ('o' in nmrls or 'g' in nmrls):
        print(nmrls)
```

Something similar could also be achieved using [list comprehension:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
x = [word for word in x if len(word) >= 7 and ('o' in word or 'g' in word)]
```

Comment: Thank you it makes sense, but why not use the count.

Comment: @datagalz I suggest not using a count simply because it adds unnecessary code complexity. `len()` is generally the pythonic way to find the length of an iterable. Defining an additional, unneeded variable, especially when it can be summarized with a function, is not usually pythonic.